# Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint even though i use proper indexes and query scheme

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016, unique-constraint

I have several unique indexes. For example

```
SET ansi_nulls ON 

go 

SET quoted_identifier ON 

go 

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblrelatedwords] 
  ( 
     [cl_orgwordid]           [BIGINT] NOT NULL, 
     [cl_relatedwordid]       [BIGINT] NOT NULL, 
     [cl_relatedwordtypecode] [SMALLINT] NOT NULL, 
     [cl_relation_sourceid]   [TINYINT] NOT NULL, 
     CONSTRAINT [PK_tblSeeAlso] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ( [cl_orgwordid] ASC, 
     [cl_relatedwordid] ASC, [cl_relatedwordtypecode] ASC )WITH (pad_index = OFF 
     , statistics_norecompute = OFF, ignore_dup_key = OFF, allow_row_locks = on, 
     allow_page_locks = on, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY] 
  ) 
ON [PRIMARY] 

go 

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tblrelatedwords] 
  ADD CONSTRAINT [DF_tblSeeAlso_cl_RelatedWordTypeCode] DEFAULT ((255)) FOR 
  [cl_RelatedWordTypeCode] 

go
```

When i use below query systematic even though i check with If not exists, i am still getting the below error

```
IF NOT EXISTS
  ( SELECT 1
   FROM tblRelatedWords
   WHERE (cl_OrgWordId=@cl_OrgWordId
          AND cl_RelatedWordId=@cl_RelatedWordId
          AND cl_RelatedWordTypeCode=@cl_RelatedWordTypeCode)
     OR (cl_OrgWordId=@cl_RelatedWordId
         AND cl_RelatedWordId=@cl_OrgWordId
         AND cl_RelatedWordTypeCode=@cl_RelatedWordTypeCode) ) BEGIN
INSERT INTO tblRelatedWords
VALUES (@cl_OrgWordId,
        @cl_RelatedWordId,
        @cl_RelatedWordTypeCode,
        @cl_Relation_SourceId) END
```

Error

```
Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_tblSeeAlso'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.tblRelatedWords'. The duplicate key value is (11439364, 2495501, 243).  The statement has been terminated.
```

Yes multiple threads are adding to the same table however aren't IF NOT EXISTS supposed to prevent such cases?

Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP1-CU2) (KB4013106) - 13.0.4422.0 (X64)

Comment: What transaction isolation level are you using for your queries? What's the default for the database?

Comment: You can use `merge` statement. Or you can enclose your batch into transaction and use `with (updlock)` hint in `if exists(select ...` part of your query.

Comment: The `NOT EXISTS` and the `INSERT` are two separate operations and therefore there is a gap between them in which the same record can be inserted. For more information on race conditions in SQL Server [this is quite informative](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/dang/archive/2007/10/28/Conditional-INSERTUPDATE-Race-Condition.aspx), and as far as I know, the best thread safe solution is to use `MERGE .. WITH (HOLDLOCK)` as discussed [in this article](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/dang/archive/2009/01/31/UPSERT-Race-Condition-With-MERGE.aspx).

Comment: @alroc whatever the default is

Comment: @Arvo can you post your updlock answer

Comment: @GarethD yes i also thought about gap and it makes sense. however it seems like merge still can cause inconsistency according to the article you have pointed

Comment: ah i guess best approach is modifying select statement with WITH (UPDLOCK, HOLDLOCK) right?

Comment: Is serializable the default for SQL Server?

Comment: @McMurphy nope not always positive, it may exists or may not exists

Comment: Does the error occur at VERB time or COMMIT time? Commit-time evaluation of constraints and more thatn 1 insert? i.e. in a loop?

Comment: @McMurphy i dont know. i have found from the logs that it has failed with the error i have posted. can you also check this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43869042/preventing-conditional-insert-update-race-condition-in-ms-sql

Comment: Apparently SQL Server now supports deferable constraints. (Needed if Table A has a FK to Table B and vice versa) Anyway not the default so if you can't find "defer" in your code or stored procedures then it's probably irrelevant.

Comment: @McMurphy yes i dont have any defer. the  question contains full table details and the query details